# Is is secure to transfer data between S3 and my data center using AWS S3 SDK?

Tags: java, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use AWS SDK to upload/download files from a private S3 bucket using Java to our data center.

I am planning to use following code

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, fileToUpload));
S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
```

Will the data be traveling between S3 and our Datacenter in plain text or will  it use some form of secure transport like SSL?

Answer (score 4):

The default for communication is SSL.  While HTTP is available, you would have to specifically use it.  For example, from [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html), you would have to do something like:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials); 
s3Client.setEndpoint("http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

with the endpoints taken from [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Since you're using the defaults, your communication is via SSL/HTTPS.

Comment: That answers the question. I notice AWS now has AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credentials, encryptionMaterials); Is that for encrypting the content of the file being stored?

Comment: @SimsSmith yes, as the documentation clearly says "Used to perform client-side encryption for storing data securely in S3". It is used to encrypted the data on the client side, before transmitting it to S3.